# Android AWS Cognito - Keep user signed-in long-term like on iOS (Cognito YourUserPools Sample)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm making an app for both Android and iOS which uses AWS Cognito. I'm following the Cognito YourUserPools Sample for both platforms. In the [Swift](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Swift) sample the user seems to stay signed-in permanently (or some long term) until they deliberately sign-out, which I imagine has to do with the iOS platform and its keystore. However, with the [Android](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo) sample, the user would have to sign-in on every launch unless the subsequent re-launches follow shortly after signing-in.

How can I properly have the app keep the user signed-in "long-term" similar to the iOS sample?

Comment: In Android, you can persist the Access and Refresh Token in the SharedPreferences in the ApplicationContext.

Comment: Is it possible to see example code of this? I'm not certain where to look.

EDIT: Nevermind I found it.